# large blobs in mysql database are making my website slow

Tags: php, mysql, database, amazon-web-services, large-data

I have website running under drupal 7 CMS with mysql database and i'm facing a problem in the data base because i have to store a lot of large texts in blob type in 3 tables in the current time the size of each table from those 3 tables is about 10 GB.

I use on those 3 tables 'insert' and 'select' query.

although my server is 16 GB RAM but I believe due to the database my website is so slow, what is your suggestions to solve this problem ? How large websites deal with mega data problems ?

I'm thinking to put this 3 tables in another database also in another server ?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution will depend a lot on the nature of your site and exactly what you're looking for, so it's very difficult to give a concise answer here.

One common approach, for sites which aren't extremely latency-sensitive, is to actually store the textual/binary data in another service (e.g., [Amazon's S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/)), and then only keep a key to that service stored in your database. Your application can then perform a database query, retrieve the key, and either send a request to the service directly (if you want to process the BLOB server-side) or instruct the client application to download the file from the service.

Comment: thank you for your answer in my website i store a lot of emails with the content so i insert this emails at the begining after that i select from this table to print to users !! and i thing going to amazon's s3 its not good option for my case because i have a loooot of incoming data